# SQL Server 2012 installation silently fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 running setup.exe on 64-bit windows 8. After the "please wait" dialog, the installation center comes up. I chose "New SQL Server stand-alone installation", getting a new "please wait" dialog and then this window:

[image]

I press ok and comes to a dialog where the product key is input, I press next and accept the license terms, next again, leaves as it is, press next, the installation seems to start.

This should happen according to the text in the window: Scan for product updates, download setup files, extract setup files, install setup files.

After a while, the window dissapears and I get no message.

Nothing seems to be installed.

What really happened?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqljourney/archive/2012/05/07/sql-2008-2008-r2-setup-disappears-fails-when-installing-setup-support-files.aspx

Comment: Did you find anything interesting in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ixrRfGHc

Answer (score 3):

If this is RTM, I would recommend slipstreaming SP1 + the latest CU into setup before installing, and making sure you install from a local source rather than an ISO, network folder, external drive, etc.

To slipstream you can just [download SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575) (likely SQLServer2012SP1-KB2674319-x64-ENU.exe) and/or a CU ([CU3 is here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/this-hotfix-is-no-longer-available-24b7929a-eacd-c259-f6fa-d626aad3236a); CU4 should be released any moment now) to a folder (say `C:\SP1Updates\`), extract the files (you should end up with .exe files like `SQLServer2012-KBxxxxxxx-x64.exe` and you can ignore or get rid of the source `4xxxxx_intl_x64_zip.exe` files) and then run setup from a command line like so:

```
setup.exe /UpdateEnabled=1 /UpdateSource="C:\SP1Updates\"
```

Or you can download the slipstreamed ISO from here (they have `slipstream` in the name, just note they contain SP1 but no CU):

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Service Pack 1 (SP1)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575) (download link)

Some blog posts that go into greater detail about slipstreaming:

- [Installing SQL Server 2012 + Service Pack 1 + SP1 Cumulative update in one installation using SQL Server 2012 Product Update](https://web.archive.org/web/20151011183926/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ai/archive/2013/01/14/installing-sql-server-2012-service-pack-1-sp1-cumulative-update-in-one-installation-using-sql-server-2012-product-update.aspx)
- [How to create an SQL Server 2012 installer with integrated CU1 (Product Updates – Slipstream)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170322074736/https://lensql.net/2012/05/14/how-to-create-a-sql-server-2012-installer-with-integrated-cu1-product-updates-slipstream/)
- [SQL Server 2012: Merged Product Updates (Slipstream)](https://www.lucasnotes.com/2012/05/sql-server-2012-merged-product-updates.html)

You might also try the technique here, and you should be able to use slipstream here as well if you want (you'll just need to use a different `PatchLevel`, `11.00.3000.00` I believe):

- [SQL 2008/2008 R2/2012 setup disappears/fails when installing Setup Support files](https://web.archive.org/web/20151124045541/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqljourney/archive/2012/05/07/sql-2008-2008-r2-setup-disappears-fails-when-installing-setup-support-files.aspx)

In case that blog post disappears, I'm going to steal the content and paraphrase (since part of the instructions seem incorrect):

> 1. Save the following in a .reg file and merge to populate the registry:

> ```
>     Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
> ```

```
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Bootstrap]
    "BootstrapDir"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Setup Bootstrap\\"
```

> ```
>     [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Bootstrap\Setup]
> ```

```
    "PatchLevel"="11.00.2100.60"
```

> 2. Next, copy <s>the following files and folders from</s> all of the media to:

> ```
>      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2012
> ```

> 3. Next, run setup from the new location, and it should proceed beyond the point of error this time.

(Note that I haven't tried this technique.)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a patch on SQL 2008 R2.  It just silently died.  I ended up calling Microsoft and documented the process we went through to find the solution.  While I realize your problem is going to be different from the one I had the process may be of some help.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1262389-391-4.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8899/discussion-between-kenneth-fisher-and-anders-linden)

Answer (score 1):

For me, solution was just to uninstall Setup Files from through Control Panel

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the ideas, my issue stemmed from residue from previous installation trys.  The clue was in the setup logs found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\  I went ahead and found all traces in the registry, programs & features, and program folders and eliminated them.